# Run onion service from tor browser

Tags: onion-services

I was wondering if it would be possible to connect two tor browser directly. This would be great for P2P applications running in the browser. I was wondering something like one browser creating a hidden service and the other connection to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible at this time. You need to use the standalone client on Linux or Mac.  You can also use it on Linux Subsystem for Windows but it's experimental at best.